# Randomly selecting dataframe column. Avoid sampling same column again

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there a way to random pick a column in a dataframe and then avoid randomly pick it again? This should pick a random column

```
random_data_vector = data[, sample(ncol(data), 1)]
```

but I'm not sure how to avoid picking the column again. I thought about removing the column completely but there might be a better approach

Answer (score 2):

You can first sample the columns with

```
random_cols <- sample(ncol(data))
```

and then select the random vectors like this

```
random_data_vector1 <- my_df[, random_cols[1]]
random_data_vector2 <- my_df[, random_cols[2]]
```

The default setting of `sample` is `replace = FALSE`, thus in the `random_cols` vector you won't have duplicated numbers and you won't select one column twice.